# PFQuery possible bug when updating key value

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery

I have the following code to retrieve all new 'Departments' from my Parse table...

Upon first application run on device, I create a date for last year.

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *days = [NSDateComponents new];
[days setDay:-365];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *lastYear = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:days toDate:now options:0];
[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:lastYear forKey:@"lastUpdate";
[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Then I run a background PFQuery ...

```
lastDate = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lastUpdate";
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Departments"];
[query whereKey:@"createdAt" greaterThan:lastDate];
```

This query works. Once the appropriate departments are returned, I place the updated (current date) in the NSUserDefaults.

```
[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"lastUpdate"];
[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

When I run this query again (see below), without any update to my 'Departments' table on the backend, I should receive NO Departments ( device update date is now greater ).

However, I get the same result set returned again when I run against the new date...

```
lastDate = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lastUpdate";
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Departments"];
[query whereKey:@"createdAt" greaterThan:lastDate];
```

Note: I've logged all dates and the dates in NSUserDefaults are correct. I've also checked the dates in the backend and everything looks right. I've also cleared the PFQuery cache before each run and set the cache policy to network only, just to remove caching weirdness.

What's really strange is that if I kill the app and run it again, the query then works as expected ( no results )...

```
lastDate = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lastUpdate";
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Departments"];
[query whereKey:@"createdAt" greaterThan:lastDate];
```

After playing with this for a couple days, the only conclusion I can come to is that this is a bug in PFQuery. I'm changing the value, but the query is not adhering to this updated value in which it to check against, unless I kill the app and run it again.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Just to be sure, have you tried logging the results count when the query returns?

Comment: Yes, I've logged the dates and the dates are as expected. Very strange.